# Sencha Touch store filtering issue with web sql

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, sencha-touch, store

I am using websql as store's proxy in Sencha Touch. I need to use filter on a store as well as the data in the store has to be saved in the web sql database. The data is set in the database but the filter is not working. I have also tried remoteFilter but it is of no help. Following is the code snippet:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.DummyStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    model: 'MyApp.model.DummyModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'sql',
        database: 'MyApp',
        table: 'Data',
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
  }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.DummyModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [{
        name: 'firstname'
    }, {
        name: 'lastname'
    }]
  }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.controller.App',{
extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
config:{
    refs:{
        view:'view'
    },
    control:{
        view:{
            initialize: 'filterStore'
        }
    }
},
filterStore: function() {
    var me=this;
    Ext.getStore('DummyStore').filter('firstname','abc', true);
  }
});
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by web sql? Sqlite database or the web version of mssql?

Comment: @Tarabass, It is the Sencha sql proxy. Sencha uses websql, Ext.data.proxy.Sql

Comment: Do you get any data out of it? Any errors in devtools of Chrome? Does the store even load at all?

Comment: In your example, you didn't add `storeId,autoload` property. Does in the the list is even showing any data? Have you tried calling ` Ext.getStore('DummyStore').load();` after filtering it?